# kubernetes: ssh to a pod from another pod in same namespace

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-helm

I have created 4 containers within a single namespace( All have bash ).
I want to ssh to container1 from container2.

I want to get some values like: the "image" used to create the container, any "Environment variables" etc.

How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Pritish

Comment: i have only 1 question - why do you need to ssh from any container to another?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the Kubernetes API.

Comment: I am writing a helm test which will test the containers deployed during helm install. 
Using helm chart I am creating 4 containers from different images and having different env variables. 
I am able to test the services created by using CURL, but if I want to test the env variables or images etc I need to do a ssh to the containers.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to get necessary info to use with ssh, you could extract those info via [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api), and make sure that your pods are ssh-enabled as well.

IMHO, the intuitive way to check for deployment status is using readiness check. In that case, you could run a bash script to check for specific environment variables, if those info is not available then those pods would be not allowed to server traffic.

For e.g:

```
readinessProbe:
  periodSeconds: 60
  exec:
    command:
    - "/bin/bash"
    - "-c"
    - if [ "$env" != "{{ .Values.environment }}" ]; then exit 1; fi
```